# I am trying to solve a system of nonlinear equations in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

I'm trying to solve the following equation programmatically:

```
(ax−x0)^2 + (ay−y0)^2 = r^2
(bx−x0)^2 + (by−y0)^2 = (r+330bs)^2
(cx−x0)^2 + (cy−y0)^2 = (r+330cs)^2
```

`ax,bx,cx,ay,by,cy,bs` and `cs` are parameters, all which i get at runtime.
I'm trying to find `x0` and `y0`, but when i feed this into **algebra.js** it errors out.
I'm a high-school student so i didn't study high-end math (I have found solutions revolving matrices, which I didn't learn yet)

Would love some help with this, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The code i have used with **algebra.js** was:

```
/*
    a = ax*
    b = bx*
    c = cx*
    d = ay*
    e = by*
    f = cy*
    g = x0
    h = y0
    i = r
    j = bs*
    k = cs*
*/
var eq = algebra.parse("(a−g)^2 + (d−h)^2 = i^2");
eq.solveFor("g");
```

I then wanted to put the answer in the second equation and solve that, but that didn't work.

EDIT2:

The source of this equation is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187819/sound-triangulation) by the way.

Comment: Could you post the code you have created so far, in particular the part where you create and pass on the equations to algebra.js?

Comment: What error do you get? Or does the solve just return undefined?

Comment: @Jaco "Token error at character − at position 2"

Comment: @Jaco "Token error at character − at position 3" doesn't seem like it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the minus sign itself.
Try this with your minus sign i copied from here

```
console.log("−".charCodeAt());
```

you get 8722 http://www.codetable.net/decimal/8722
now with minus sign that i typed in on my keyboard

```
console.log("-".charCodeAt());
```

i get 45 http://www.codetable.net/decimal/45

and with charCode 45 your code works, well at least for me

That's all i know, i have no explanation to this sorry :)

Comment: The lexer for algebra.js does indeed only support the minus with charCode 45, see the source code on GitHub. You must have copied and pasted the other minus sign from a webpage.

Comment: @Jaco I'm not sure what you mean. When i copy/paste FunnyDaven's code i get the mentioned error. When i replace minus sign it works. Did you try yourself?

Comment: There are different minus signs in Unicode and only the minus sign you enter with your keyboard (charCode 45) will be parsed successfully by algebra.js.